Micronaut Cache Caffeine's Expire After Write not working
I'm trying to follow Micronaut guide and I've created a simple project. All I wanted to test is removing entries from the cache after 1 minute, but it seems it doesn't work. Could you tell me, what am I missing please? I also tried to implement RemovalListener, but it didn't work and I also don't know, what should the handler in that example do.
My code:
application.properties
    micronaut.application.name=caffeinecachetest
    micronaut.caches.user.expire-after-write=1m
    micronaut.caches.user.listen-to-removals=true
    micronaut.caches.user.listen-to-evictions=true

@Serdeable
public class User {

    private List<String> roles;

    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" + "roles=" + roles + '}';
    }
}

@Singleton
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "user")
public class CaffeineService {

    Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<>();

    @Cacheable
    public User getUser(String authorization) {
        return users.get(authorization);
    }

    @CachePut(parameters = {"authorization"})
    public void storeUser(String authorization, User user) {
        users.put(authorization, user);
    }

    @CacheInvalidate(parameters = {"authorization"})
    public void removeUser(String authorization) {
        users.remove(authorization);
    }
}

@Controller
public class CaffeineController {

    private final CaffeineService caffeineService;

    public CaffeineController(CaffeineService caffeineService) {
        this.caffeineService = caffeineService;
    }

    @Get("/{authorization}")
    public User getUser(String authorization) {
        User user = caffeineService.getUser(authorization);
        if (user != null) {
            System.out.println("User found in cache");
            return user;
        }
        System.out.println("Creating new User");
        caffeineService.storeUser(authorization, createUser());
        return null; // I don't want to return it, when we create it
    }

    private User createUser() {
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add("first");
        roles.add("second");
        User user = new User();
        user.setRoles(roles);
        return user;
    }
}


By default the cache will wait until other, unrelated activity before doing its maintenance work. You could try adding a scheduler if you want it to react promptly.
